# Sufficient conditions for integration by parts in higher dimensions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, reference-request

If $\Omega\subset {\mathbb R}^n$ is a bounded open set with $C^1$ boundary and $\nu$ denotes the outward unit normal to $\partial \Omega$, then
the following formula holds for every pair of $C^1$ functions $u$ and $v$:

$$\int_\Omega v \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} = \int_{\partial \Omega} 
uv\,  \nu_i - \int_\Omega u \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i} 
$$
($\nu_i$ denotes the $i$-th component of the vector $\nu$; moreover the functions $u$, $v$ and their partial derivatives are assumed to have continuous extensions up to the boundary).

I am hoping it would also be true if $v$ were instead only bounded and $C^1$ on $\Omega$.

References are appreciated.

I should mentioned that this has been ask before here: [Find a rigorous reference that prove the following integration by parts formula in higher dimension?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263867/find-a-rigorous-reference-that-prove-the-following-integration-by-parts-formula).  I cannot access the reference provided so I'm asking the question again.