# Integration by parts between two functions of two variables and one integration variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is it possible to do integration by parts on this?

I'm trying to manipulate the 2nd term in equation (3.109) at https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/plasma/Plasma/node38.html to look more like the 1st and 3rd terms, where the derivative is on "w". I think a simpler version of the problem looks like this:

$$ \int g(x,y) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y) dy $$

From what I can tell, the answer is supposed to be

$$ \int g(x,y) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y) dy = \int  f(x,y) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x,y) dy $$

Note that $f$ and $g$ quickly fall to 0 at infinity, and the integral is over the infinite domain (surface terms are zero).

It might be useful to know that there is also some function $u=u(x,y) = x-y$ and $g$ is a function of $u$.

Attempt:

In single variable calculus, integration by parts usually looks like
$$\int udv = uv - \int vdu$$

In this case, we can consider

$$ df(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy $$

Comment: I think this is the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263867/find-a-rigorous-reference-that-prove-the-following-integration-by-parts-formula?rq=1  . The formula is really simple but the proof is probably non-trivial.

Comment: The other answer assumes both variables are integrated over, though.

Comment: It should be possible to take the derivative with respect to the variable that we don't want (y) to make it matched the desired form. However, everything still appears to be off by a factor of -1.